# Matrix manipulation trick (to describe in a quadratic-form like): $| a^H X |^2$ (absolute square is componentwise)?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a \in M_{n,1}(\mathbb{C})$ and $X = [x_1,\cdots,x_p] \in M_{n,p}(\mathbb{C})$, where $x_i \in M_{n,1}(\mathbb{C})$.

If we perform the following operation *componentwise*, i.e.,
\begin{align}
| a^H X |^2 
&= \left|a^H [x_1,\cdots,x_p]\right|^2 \\
&= \left[|a^H x_1|^2,\cdots, |a^H x_p|^2\right] \\
&=  \left[x_1^H a a^H x_1,\cdots, x_p^H a a^H x_p \right] \\
&= \textrm{in terms of }  X \textrm{ and } a \textrm{ only?}
\end{align}

**Question**:

How to describe such operation (neatly) in terms of the matrix $X$ and $a$ only, but *not* in terms of the individual column vectors of matrix $X = [x_1,\cdots,x_p]$? Is it possible? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is $|a^HX|^2 =X^Haa^HX$.

Comment: No, unfortunately, it doesn't seem so to me because $X^H aa^H X$ is a matrix of $p \times p$ not a row vector $1 \times p$. agree?

Comment: Then the other way around. Is $a^HX$ a row vector?

Comment: Yes, it's a row vector, isn't it? $a^H$, $1 \times n$ row vector, multiplied with $X$, $n \times p$ matrix, would render $1 \times p$ vector...

Comment: If $v$ is a row vector, we have $|v|^2 =vv^H$, so it's now $a^HXX^Ha$ (I indeed wrote it in the wrong direction in my first comment).

Comment: No, I am sorry to say $a^H X X^H a$ will be a scalar. Please notice that the absolute square operation is elementwise/componentwise.

Comment: Isn't it just the elementwise/Hadamard product of each component with its conjugate, i.e. $$(a^TX^*)\odot(a^HX)$$

Comment: @greg that's true. Thank you so much.